# can you set the screensaver to go on less than 1 minute?

Tags: settings, screensaver

I'm actually using an older version of xubuntu currently (only temporarily). I mainly use my computer for listening to music, and if i want to skip a song, change volume, or see what song is playing, I basically want the screensaver to to turn on as fast as possible, afterwards. In the screensaver options it allows you to adjust the amount of idle time when for screensaver to turn on. The increments, however, are in minutes, so I can't have it go on less than one minute. I've tried to type .5 in the field, but it just changes it back to 1.

so I basically want to know if someone knows someway, or perhaps some third party screensaver software that lets you adjust the time for the screensaver less than one minute.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the monitor to turn off (without immediately activating the screensaver), you could execute this command once you logged in:

```
xset dpms 10
```

This will make the monitor enter suspend in 10 seconds. You can read more about this in the [manual page of `xset`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/xset.1).

The screensaver still needs to be activated in a different way, but a minute should not be problematic if all you want is to save power.

Comment: Thank you, that appears to work. 

I want it to be less than a minute not so much for the power saving benefits, but more for the fact that the bright screen is annoying, and I just ignore it and to bump to the tunes.

As for your fix, is there anyway I can disable it, without turning off the computer, or logging out?

Comment: In the same manual page you can see that `xset dpms 0` to disable the suspend delay. However, I suggest that you instead a high delay just in case you are away from your computer for a while (like `xset dpms 900` for 15 minutes).